# Macro to assign task

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to use Excel VBA to automate a process of assigning 2 checkers to each task in a list of tasks.

There is a sheet containing the task list, the task count may change daily.

[image: task list]

There is also a sheet containing the checkers list, which lists the available checkers and their status on that day.

[image: checkers list]

I need to assign two different checkers (with status of "In") to each task, and also try to assign the task evenly so that each checker is assigned approximately the same number of tasks.

Can anyone please share some ideas of how this can be done using a macro? Thank you so so much in advance!

Comment: You could loop the task list and filter the checker list or loop that too, then assign if they are in. But please tell us where the issue is you need help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try using the next way. The following code calculates how many repetitions of each checkers pair si necessary, makes random such pairs between the checkers name and place them in the necessary array. In case of odd number of checkers, the code make pairs between the last remained name and all the rest, until  filling the necessary array. The next code uses arrays and working mostly in the memory, should be very fast:

```
Sub AllocateTasks()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastRow As Long, rngChk As Range, arrTsk, arrChk, arrInit
 Dim tasksNo As Long, maxTsk As Long, minTsk As Double, rndNumber As Long, filt As String
 Dim firstChk As String, secondChk As String, boolEven As Boolean, rest As Long, boolOver As Boolean
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 lastR = ws.Range("B" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 lastRow = ws.Range("E" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 
 Set rngChk = ws.Range("B2:B" & lastR) 'the range of checkers status
 'place in an array the available checkers:
 arrChk = filter(Evaluate("transpose(if(" & rngChk.Offset(, 1).address(0, 0) & "=""In""," & rngChk.address(0, 0) & ",FALSE))"), False, False)
 arrInit = arrChk
 
 If (UBound(arrChk) + 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then boolEven = True 'in case of even checkers number is available
 'Debug.Print Join(arrChk, "|"): 'only to see the unique available checker array in Immediate Window
 
 arrTsk = ws.Range("E2:G" & lastRow).Value2 'place the tasks range in an array for faster processing
 tasksNo = UBound(arrTsk) 'how many tasks to be processed
 
 minTsk = tasksNo / (UBound(arrChk) + 1) * 2 - IIf(boolEven, 0, 1) 'minimum times for a checkers pair
 
 rest = tasksNo - Int(tasksNo / Int(minTsk)) * Int(minTsk): ' how many times to add 1 to minTsk pairs
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrChk) + 1 'iterate between the available checkers array elements
    Randomize
    rndNumber = Int((UBound(arrChk) - LBound(arrChk) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(arrChk)) 'random number of the array elements
    If firstChk = "" Then
        firstChk = arrChk(rndNumber)  'first checker randomly chosen
    Else
        secondChk = arrChk(rndNumber) 'second checker randomly chosen
    End If
    filt = arrChk(rndNumber) & "##$$@": arrChk(rndNumber) = filt 'place an anusual string to replace the used element
    arrChk = filter(arrChk, filt, False)   'eliminate the already used checker name from the array
    
    If firstChk <> "" And secondChk <> "" Then 'place the checkers in the array if both of them have been chosen
        For j = 1 To Int(minTsk) + IIf(rest > 0, 1, 0) 'add a unit for each  case
            k = k + 1
            arrTsk(k, 2) = firstChk: arrTsk(k, 3) = secondChk 'place the checkers names in the array
        Next j
        rest = rest - 1 'decrease it to limit the over minimum number of same pair repeatitions
        If boolEven Then 'if there is an Even number of available checkers
            firstChk = "": secondChk = "" 'all the time the checkers names are reinitialized
        Else
          If i = UBound(arrInit) Then 'in case of the last remained checker name:
            For j = 1 To UBound(arrTsk) - k 'fill the last remained elements using the last odd checker name
                k = k + 1
                arrTsk(k, 2) = arrChk(UBound(arrChk))
                If arrTsk(k, 2) <> arrInit(j - 1) Then
                   arrTsk(k, 3) = arrInit(j - IIf(boolOver, 0, 1)) 'make pairs between last remained checker and all the rest
                Else
                    arrTsk(k, 3) = arrInit(j): boolOver = True 'boolean variable to add a unit, to avoid making pair with the same name...
                End If
            Next j
            If k >= UBound(arrTsk) Then Exit For
          Else
            firstChk = "": secondChk = "" 'reinitializing the checkers name, except for the last odd one case
          End If
        End If
    End If
 Next i

 'drop the processed array content, at once:
 ws.Range("I2").Resize(UBound(arrTsk), 3).Value2 = arrTsk
 
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

The above solution **tries answering the question as it has been formulated**. I mean, it is suitable to make such allocations for daily tasks. If some tasks remained unfinished next day, **the involved checkers must not be available**. Otherwise, the algorithm of allocation must be well defined and a much more complex code will be necessary...

It processes both ranges **in the same (active) sheet**, checkers list in columns A:C and Tasks in columns E:G. Then, it returns also there, starting from "I2". These ranges can be easily adapted to your need. The idea of returning in a different place, is to firstly evaluate the result and if it suits your need, just change the last line where the processet array drops its elements from "I2" to "E2"...

Comment: @qiao Didn't you find some time to test the above suggested solution? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!, the tasks are assigned to two different checkers evenly. The task list gets updated daily, so it should not involve the complex situation you reminded. I will try to learn about the logic in your code! thanks a lot

Comment: @qiao I tried commenting each code line which I thought that maybe it possible to not be understood, but If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: hi @FaneDuru, if I only need the checkers data to output to a fixed cell, for example, output the checkers array to cell B2 in the " Task" sheet, how should I modify the code? Because the task list actually does not has the number, instead it is a list of tasks descriptions for each task, tried many times but I can't get it right. Thanks!

Comment: @qiao I'm afraid I cannot get you... What should I understand by "output the checkers array to cell B2"? Do you mean, instead of commented line `'Debug.Print Join(arrChk, "|")` to make the code returning the array of available checkers in the B2 cell (separated by "|", or in cells starting from B2 to the last necessary column)? Or what?

Comment: hi @FaneDuru, my thought is to only return the two columns of checkers( checker1 and checker2) data to fill the blanks from cell B2 to C& lastRow in the "Task sheet", hope this is clear to you, thank you!

Comment: @qiao I am still confused... Isn't that what the code does? I do not have the data to be tested, anymore. Looking to the code, it places in an array columns E:G, where F:G are columns to receive the random checkers. If so, what do you want saying? To not place the tasks number in the array and do it only for checkers? Or, what? I was talking about the sample code which shows how to deal with the problem. If you have two sheets and the processed range is different, of course, you should extrapolate to your real range...

Comment: hi @Fane, yes, I don't need to place the tasks number in the array and do it only for checkers.

Comment: hi @FaneDuru, can you kindly advise me about the below line of code? thank you.    filt = arrChk(rndNumber) & "##$$@": arrChk(rndNumber) = filt

Comment: @qiao This adds that strange string to the `arrChk` respective element. Then give to that element the concatenated value. Respectively, if `arrChk(rndNumber)` is "Checker 3", this array element becomes "Checker 3##$$@". Using `Filter` for an array it eliminates the elements containing the strange string ( "##$$@"), which is very improbable to already exist in the name of any checker... Having an array (`arr`) of "John, Helen, Adam" and using `arr = Filter(arr, Helen, False)` the new resulted array will have only "John" and "Adam". The idea is to **eliminate each already used random checker**.

Comment: Thank you. I was using this macro to assign tasks recently, and I found few issues: 1. When we have 20 tasks and 11 or 9 available checkers, the tasks are not evenly assigned to the checkers; 2. When there are 7 available checkers and 20 tasks, the macro gives a runtime error 9. Could you kindly advise? thank you!!

Comment: @qiao I don't even have the testing environment... Please, send me the workbook in discussion and clearly explain what problem you have, in which circumstances. You can find my personal mail in my user profile.

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru, I sent you an email.

Comment: @qiao I did not receive any mail. Please, check the mail account spelling...

Comment: hi @FaneDuru, I sent to this address: ivangu@yahoo.com, is this the correct email address of yours? thanks!

Comment: @qiao The address looks OK. If you did not received a notification that the account has a problem, this means that the message left your computer. I will check in my spam folders. I receive a lot of mails I do not need and I also have configurated some rules for some other folders. I will also check them, but not now. I have a lot of things to do...

Comment: I must confess that it does not raise any error when run the code. But I find a way to make it more efficient in terms of balanced tasks assigning. Please, download the updated file from [here](https://easyupload.io/c96oww) and send some feedback after testing it. Did you run the code only by pressing the button I provided, but also running the called Sub from VBE (Visual for Applications Editor)? In the second case, the code was depending of the active sheet, which should be the one keeping the button. Now, I adapt it to also work if you run it from VBE and the active sheet is not that one.

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru, I tried the updated file.

Comment: @qiao And? Did it work as you need? Did is raise any error, or what...?

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru, I tried the updated file. I updated the code to specify the two sheets so the code does not depend on any active sheet. I used your updated code for few days, but I still get the runtime error 9 when there are 20 tasks and 6 checkers or 14 checkers. (Last time when I used the old code, I came across the same issue when there are 20 tasks and 7 or 9 available checkers.)  I still cannot figure out the cause. When I debug, I see k=21, and it tries to assign a checker to arrTsk(21,1) while we only have arrTsk(20).

Comment: hi @FaneDuru，and I don't quite understand this line: rndNumber = Int((UBound(arrChk) - LBound(arrChk) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(arrChk)), I learnt that: Int((6 * Rnd) + 1) this generate random value between 1 and 6. Why should we add 1 after UBound(arrChk) - LBound(arrChk)? I thought we only have arrTsk(UBound(arrChk) - LBound(arrChk)) and don't have arrTsk(UBound(arrChk) - LBound(arrChk) +1).

Comment: @qiao Do you have AnyDesk installed on your computer and allow a connection? I cannot imagine what's happening in your installation without seeing it... `rndNumber = Int((UBound(arrChk) - LBound(arrChk) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(arrChk)), I learnt that: Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)` returns a random number, but specifically between the respective array number of elements. You learned correct about `Int((6 * Rnd) + 1)`, but this is not enough. How can you apply what you learned to return a number **between 20 and 35**? You can learn about it trying to understand my code.

Comment: You can use 20 instead of `LBound(arrChk) + 1)` (+ 1 because `arrChk` is zero based), and 35 instead of `UBound(arrChk)`. Then, test it... I could use 1 instead of `LBound`, but sometimes I use 1 based arrays, where I should use 2. In conclusion, it is the simplest way to use it  for any array where from you need to extract random elements.